# How to save models in S3 and checkpoints in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, save, amazon-sagemaker, checkpoint

I am using Sagemaker with Tensorflow version 1.12.0 and a conda_tensorflor_p36 kernel. I am able to successfully train, evaluate the validation data, and predict in a deployed model. I am training with a training script.

I want to be able to save the model in S3 and then to load it. It supposes that the model will be automatically saved but it does not happen.

I am using the following.
In the script:

```
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--learning-rate', type=float, default=0.001)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument('--gpu-count', type=int, default=os.environ['SM_NUM_GPUS'])
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_MODEL_DIR'])
    parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING'])
    parser.add_argument('--validation', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_VALIDATION'])
        
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    epochs     = args.epochs
    lr         = args.learning_rate
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    gpu_count  = args.gpu_count
    model_dir  = args.model_dir
    training_dir   = args.training
    validation_dir = args.validation
...

    # save Keras model for Tensorflow Serving
    sess = K.get_session()
    tensorflow.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        os.path.join(model_dir, 'model/1'),
        inputs={'inputs': model.input},
        outputs={t.name: t for t in model.outputs})
```

In the notebook

```
model_path = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, model_channel)

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='train_cnn.py', 
                          role=role,
                          train_instance_count=1, 
                          train_instance_type='local',  #We use the local instance
                          framework_version='1.12', 
                          py_version='py3',
                          script_mode=True,
                          hyperparameters={'epochs': 1}, #One epoch just to check everything is ok
                          model_dir=model_path
                         )

tf_estimator.fit({'training': training_input_path, 'validation': validation_input_path})
```

I got as exit

```
Creating tmp9hs8n9sq_algo-1-xp4eu_1 ... 
Attaching to tmp9hs8n9sq_algo-1-xp4eu_12mdone
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:18,234 sagemaker-containers INFO     Imported framework sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:18,240 sagemaker-containers INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:18,523 sagemaker-containers INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:18,541 sagemaker-containers INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:18,555 sagemaker-containers INFO     Invoking user script
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Training Env:
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "additional_framework_parameters": {},
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "channel_input_dirs": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "training": "/opt/ml/input/data/training",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "validation": "/opt/ml/input/data/validation"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     },
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "current_host": "algo-1-xp4eu",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "framework_module": "sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "hosts": [
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "algo-1-xp4eu"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     ],
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "hyperparameters": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "epochs": 1,
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "model_dir": "s3://mybucket/myprefix/models"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     },
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "input_config_dir": "/opt/ml/input/config",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "input_data_config": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "training": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |             "TrainingInputMode": "File"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         },
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "validation": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |             "TrainingInputMode": "File"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         }
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     },
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "input_dir": "/opt/ml/input",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "is_master": true,
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "job_name": "sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2020-07-17-21-40-14-146",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "log_level": 20,
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "master_hostname": "algo-1-xp4eu",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "model_dir": "/opt/ml/model",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "module_dir": "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-487764570858/sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2020-07-17-21-40-14-146/source/sourcedir.tar.gz",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "module_name": "train_cnn",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "network_interface_name": "eth0",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "num_cpus": 4,
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "num_gpus": 0,
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "output_data_dir": "/opt/ml/output/data",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "output_dir": "/opt/ml/output",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "output_intermediate_dir": "/opt/ml/output/intermediate",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "resource_config": {
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "current_host": "algo-1-xp4eu",
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         "hosts": [
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |             "algo-1-xp4eu"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |         ]
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     },
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     "user_entry_point": "train_cnn.py"
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | }
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Environment variables:
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_HOSTS=["algo-1-xp4eu"]
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME=eth0
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_HPS={"epochs":1,"model_dir":"s3://mybucket/myprefix/models"}
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_USER_ENTRY_POINT=train_cnn.py
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_FRAMEWORK_PARAMS={}
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG={"current_host":"algo-1-xp4eu","hosts":["algo-1-xp4eu"]}
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_INPUT_DATA_CONFIG={"training":{"TrainingInputMode":"File"},"validation":{"TrainingInputMode":"File"}}
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR=/opt/ml/output/data
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_CHANNELS=["training","validation"]
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_CURRENT_HOST=algo-1-xp4eu
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_MODULE_NAME=train_cnn
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_LOG_LEVEL=20
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_FRAMEWORK_MODULE=sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_INPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/input
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_INPUT_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/ml/input/config
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/output
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_NUM_CPUS=4
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_NUM_GPUS=0
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_MODEL_DIR=/opt/ml/model
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_MODULE_DIR=s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-487764570858/sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2020-07-17-21-40-14-146/source/sourcedir.tar.gz
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"training":"/opt/ml/input/data/training","validation":"/opt/ml/input/data/validation"},"current_host":"algo-1-xp4eu","framework_module":"sagemaker_tensorflow_container.training:main","hosts":["algo-1-xp4eu"],"hyperparameters":{"epochs":1,"model_dir":"s3://mybucket/myprefix/models"},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"training":{"TrainingInputMode":"File"},"validation":{"TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2020-07-17-21-40-14-146","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1-xp4eu","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-487764570858/sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-2020-07-17-21-40-14-146/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"train_cnn","network_interface_name":"eth0","num_cpus":4,"num_gpus":0,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1-xp4eu","hosts":["algo-1-xp4eu"]},"user_entry_point":"train_cnn.py"}
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_USER_ARGS=["--epochs","1","--model_dir","s3://mybucket/myprefix/models"]
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_OUTPUT_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=/opt/ml/output/intermediate
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING=/opt/ml/input/data/training
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_CHANNEL_VALIDATION=/opt/ml/input/data/validation
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_HP_EPOCHS=1
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | SM_HP_MODEL_DIR=s3://mybucket/myprefix/models
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | PYTHONPATH=/opt/ml/code:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/python36.zip:/usr/lib/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Invoking script with the following command:
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | /usr/bin/python train_cnn.py --epochs 1 --model_dir s3://mybucket/myprefix/models
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Collecting matplotlib
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/ae/81b1c98ae97350711adb021ee12ea678b37f608ec2faa35c3a7db11795fa/matplotlib-3.3.0-1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 11.5MB 4.3MB/s eta 0:00:01
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/23/147de658aabbf968324551ea22c0c13a00284c4ef49a77002e91f79657b7/kiwisolver-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 29.2MB/s ta 0:00:01
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.3)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 (from matplotlib)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/bb/488841f56197b13700afd5658fc279a2025a39e22449b7cf29864669b15d/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 25.2MB/s ta 0:00:01
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Collecting pillow>=6.2.0 (from matplotlib)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/bf/92385b4262178ca22b34f82e0e09c2922eb351fe39f3cc7b8ba9ea555b41/Pillow-7.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 15.3MB/s ta 0:00:01
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Installing collected packages: kiwisolver, cycler, pyparsing, pillow, matplotlib
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |   Found existing installation: Pillow 6.0.0
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |     Uninstalling Pillow-6.0.0:
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |       Successfully uninstalled Pillow-6.0.0
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.2.0 matplotlib-3.3.0 pillow-7.2.0 pyparsing-2.4.7
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.2b1 is available.
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | =================================================================
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 32)        320       
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dropout (Dropout)            (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 64)        18496     
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       73856     
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 256)         295168    
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 256)         0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | flatten (Flatten)            (None, 4096)              0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               524416    
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | =================================================================
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Total params: 912,385
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Trainable params: 912,385
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Non-trainable params: 0
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | _________________________________________________________________
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | None
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Train on 26 samples, validate on 2 samples
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Epoch 1/1
algo-1-xp4eu_1  |  - 2s - loss: 1.1576 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 2.5328 - val_acc: 0.5000
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Validation loss    : 2.5328116416931152
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Validation accuracy: 0.5
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Keys dict_keys(['val_loss', 'val_acc', 'loss', 'acc'])
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/simple_save.py:85: calling SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph_and_variables (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.builder_impl) with legacy_init_op is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Instructions for updating:
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | Pass your op to the equivalent parameter main_op instead.
algo-1-xp4eu_1  | 2020-07-17 21:40:28,943 sagemaker-containers INFO     Reporting training SUCCESS
tmp9hs8n9sq_algo-1-xp4eu_1 exited with code 0
Aborting on container exit...
===== Job Complete =====
```

**But the model is not saved in the bucket. Also, what could I do If I want to have checkpoints of the model?**

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using "local" mode, your checkpointing will not be written to S3: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/estimator.py#L1124

If you do want to see your checkpointing data, you could choose a SageMaker instance type. You could set "checkpoint_s3_uri" in your estimator to allow SageMaker to upload checkpointing to a specific S3 URI

Answer (score 0):

### I got the same issue, so here is a solution to save your checkpoints and model in s3 using AWS Sagemaker

**1. Save Checkpoints:**

In the Sagemaker Training Job which is an instance of EstimatorBase, you should set `checkpoint_s3_uri` and `checkpoint_local_path`  to save the checkpoints. By setting these variables, everything in the `checkpoint_local_path` will be loaded to `checkpoint_s3_uri` :

- **checkpoint_s3_uri** = s3 bucket to save checkpoints,
- **checkpoint_local_path** = "/opt/ml/checkpoints"

**2. Save Model:**

In the Trainer, you should set variable `output_dir` and do `trainer.save_model(output_dir)` to save the model in the checkpoint s3 bucket at the end of the training:

- **output_dir** = '/opt/ml/checkpoints'

> More information here : [Use checkpoints in Amazon SageMaker (AWS
> DOC)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html)